# Java: Saving StreamResult to a file

Tags: java, xml, file, stream, sax

I am doing some data conversion(like csv) to xml with SAX then using transformer in Java.  The result is in StreamResult, and I am trying to save this result to a file.xml but I can't find way to save StreamResult into file.  am I doing this all wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your `StreamResult` should be created on the basis of a file, e.g.

```
StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(new File("/my/file.xml"));
```

If you give your `Transformer` such a `StreamResult`, it will write its result directly into the file you specified.

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with the API... but does [this link](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/445.cfm) give you what you are after?

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

//initialize StreamResult with File object to save to file
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
transformer.transform(source, result);

String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
System.out.println(xmlString);
```

Comment: The comment does not match the code.  It says it's saving to a File, but it actually writes to a String that gets println'd.

Comment: Thanks, this saved my life. If you give StreamResult a file with blanks in the name it converts them to '%20'.